# Optimize SQL server query of procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server procedure :

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE 'dbo'.'spMedicionEnergiaMaximos'
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @strFechaInicio nvarchar(50),
    @strFechaFin nvarchar(50),
    @fkTipoDato integer,
    @fkPlanta integer
AS
    DECLARE @FechaInicio datetime = CAST(@strFechaInicio AS datetime);
    DECLARE @FechaFin datetime = CAST(@strFechaFin AS datetime);
    DECLARE @FechaWhile datetime = @FechaInicio;
    DECLARE @TablaTemp table (tempFecha date,
                              cero real,
                              uno real,
                              dos real,
                              tres real,
                              cuatro real,
                              cinco real,
                              seis real,
                              siete real,
                              ocho real,
                              nueve real,
                              diez real,
                              once real,
                              doce real,
                              trece real,
                              catorce real,
                              quince real,
                              dieciseis real,
                              diecisiete real,
                              dieciocho real,
                              diecinueve real,
                              veinte real,
                              veintiuno real,
                              veintidos real,
                              veintitres real);
    WHILE @FechaWhile <= @FechaFin
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
                          FechaHora
                   FROM RegistroDatos
                   WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                     AND FechaHora >= @FechaWhile
                     AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaWhile)
                     AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @TablaTemp
            SELECT TOP 1
                   CONVERT(varchar(10), FechaHora, 103) AS Fecha,
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= @FechaWhile
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile))
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '00:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '01:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '02:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '03:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '04:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 6, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '05:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 6, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 7, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '06:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '07:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '08:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '09:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '10:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 11, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 12, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '11:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 12, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 13, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '12:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 13, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 14, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '13:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 15, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '14:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 15, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 16, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '15:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '16:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 18, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '17:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 18, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 19, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '18:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 19, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 20, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '19:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 20, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 21, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '20:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 21, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '21:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '22:00',
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           valor
                    FROM RegistroDatos
                    WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
                      AND FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile)
                      AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @FechaWhile))
                      AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
                    ORDER BY valor DESC) AS '23:00'
            FROM RegistroDatos
            WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
              AND FechaHora >= @FechaWhile
              AND FechaHora <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaWhile)
              AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta;
        END;

        SET @FechaWhile = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaWhile);
    END;
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), tempFecha, 103) AS Fecha,
           cero AS '00:00',
           uno AS '01:00',
           dos AS '02:00',
           tres AS '03:00',
           cuatro AS '04:00',
           cinco AS '05:00',
           seis AS '06:00',
           siete AS '07:00',
           ocho AS '08:00',
           nueve AS '09:00',
           diez AS '10:00',
           once AS '11:00',
           doce AS '12:00',
           trece AS '13:00',
           catorce AS '14:00',
           quince AS '15:00',
           dieciseis AS '16:00',
           diecisiete AS '17:00',
           dieciocho AS '18:00',
           diecinueve AS '19:00',
           veinte AS '20:00',
           veintiuno AS '21:00',
           veintidos AS '22:00',
           veintitres AS '23:00'
    FROM @TablaTemp;
```

I get the data from the following table:

[image: Data source table: Registro Datos]

And so should be the result of the procedure.

[image: Procedure result]

What the query does is search on the specified dates, the highest consumption, separated from hour to hour.

If you can give me a hand I would appreciate it, thank you very much!

Comment: Formatting you SQL is *so* important for good, readable, code. As for the question, all those subqueries are going to be terrible for performance. Looks like what you really want is a `PIVOT`/Cross Tab/Conditional aggregation.

Comment: Separate note, it's generally advised to not use single quotes (`'`) for delimit identification. Although you can, single quotes are normally used to denote literal strings, and using them for delimit object names can confuse. Stick to either double quotes (`"`) or (when using T-SQL) brackets (`[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation with `CASE` statements for each hour for *one* `SELECT` query. Also, try the less than operator, `<` (not `<=`), and avoid need to subtract a millisecond on the upper range limit.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMedicionEnergiaMaximos]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @strFechaInicio nvarchar(50),
    @strFechaFin nvarchar(50),
    @fkTipoDato integer,
    @fkPlanta integer
AS
    DECLARE @FechaInicio datetime = CAST(@strFechaInicio AS datetime);
    DECLARE @FechaFin datetime = CAST(@strFechaFin AS datetime);
    DECLARE @FechaWhile datetime = @FechaInicio;

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), FechaHora, 103) AS Fecha
     , MAX(CASE WHEN FechaHora >= @FechaWhile                   AND FechaHora < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile) THEN valor END) AS [00:00] 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @FechaWhile) AND FechaHora < DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile) THEN valor END) AS [01:00]
     , MAX(CASE WHEN FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 2, @FechaWhile) AND FechaHora < DATEADD(HOUR, 3, @FechaWhile) THEN valor END) AS [02:00]

     , ...    -- FILL IN MIDDLE HOURS

     , MAX(CASE WHEN FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 21, @FechaWhile) AND FechaHora < DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile) THEN valor END) AS [22:00]
     , MAX(CASE WHEN FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 22, @FechaWhile) AND FechaHora < DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile) THEN valor END) AS [23:00]
     , MAX(CASE WHEN FechaHora >= DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @FechaWhile) AND FechaHora < DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @FechaWhile) THEN valor END) AS [24:00]

FROM RegistroDatos
WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato
  AND fk_Planta = @fkPlanta
  AND FechaHora >= @FechaWhile
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), FechaHora, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the comments, I managed to make it work like this:

```
DECLARE @fkTipoDato integer = 2;
DECLARE @fkPlanta integer= 1;
DECLARE @FechaInicio datetime=CAST('2020-27-10 00:00:00' as datetime);
DECLARE @FechaFin datetime=CAST('2020-28-10 00:00:00' as datetime);
 

  SELECT CAST(FechaHora AS DATE) as [Fecha],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 0 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [00:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 1 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [01:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 2 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [02:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 3 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [03:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 4 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [04:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 5 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [05:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 6 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [06:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 7 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [07:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 8 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [08:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 9 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [09:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 10 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [10:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 11 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [11:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 12 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [12:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 13 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [13:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 14 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [14:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 15 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [15:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 16 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [16:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 17 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [17:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 18 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [18:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 19 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [19:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 20 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [20:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 21 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [21:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 22 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [22:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 23 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [23:00]
   FROM RegistroDatos
   WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato and fk_Planta = @fkPlanta and fechaHora BETWEEN @FechaInicio and DATEADD (day , 1 , @FechaFin)
  GROUP BY CAST(FechaHora AS DATE)
    ORDER BY CAST(FechaHora AS DATE) ASC
```

But, when I want to calculate the minima in the same way (changing MAX by MIN), I get all 0's.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!